# Django - context - How to pass context to ALL views

Tags: python, django, dry, django-class-based-views

Because I need to cycle through a model table to render the options/nav-links in the navbar, and the navbar is rendered on every page. Hence, I find myself passing in the same context to every class-based view and it's quite repetitive:

```py
class Xxx:
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.get_categories_with_item()
        return context
```

Is there a DRYer way to do this? Thanks!!

PS. *and also, is `*args` necessary in `get_context_data` method? I've seen code with it and code without*

Comment: you can create a navbar.html template and add it to base.html with include tags and extend base.html on all other templates

Comment: @bmons how does this answer the op's question ???

Comment: "is *args necessary in get_context_data method" => it's not necessary, and it's actually wrong - the API expects it to only support kwargs (if 'Xxx' is a standard Django CBV at least).

Comment: hahaha Thanks for pointing that out and your kind answer to my silly question. helped a lot!! always confused by it.

Comment: The question wasn't silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to write custom `context processor`

```
from django.core.context_processors import request

def custom_processor(request):
    categories = Category.objects.get_categories_with_item() 
    return {"categories": categories}
```

You need to add this function to `TEMPLATES` -> `"OPTIONS"` -> `"context_processors"`

Comment: I don't know why everyone always insist on using context processors for this use case, when a custom template tag is a much better solution on all accounts.

Comment: hey @bruno, I'm not familiar with `simple_tag` but wouldn't you have to `{% load %}` it to the pages manually? whereas `context_processor` does it automatically. The only down side I can think of is that `context processor` applies to literally ALL pages... even when that context is not needed...

Comment: Yes you will have to load your tag lib, but if you put the navigation section in the base template (which is usually the case), you only have to load it once. wrt/ context processors, there are_three_ downsides: the first is the cost (it applies to every template rendering, which is often more than "every page"), the second is that it's implicit - when looking at the template, you can't tell where the context variable comes from -, and the third is the risk of name clashes (ie if some of your views wants a `categories` context var).

Comment: @bruno actually you are right, I'm experiencing some issues mentioned in your last comments. Could you Answer this post so I can change the correct answer? if it's still possible...